# starting values for piecewise function within nls r

Tags: r, nls, piecewise

I'm looking for some advice on where I'm going wrong with attempting to fit a piecewise function.

The plot below shows degree days above 5 (DD5) against average temperature (TG).
[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGonU.png)

I've written the following function within nls, based on a previous work which specified the equation below.

```
pwise<-nls(DD5 ~ ifelse(TG>k, a/(1+exp(-(TG-T0)/b)), c+B*TG),
       data=staid01_monthly,
       start=c(k=0,a=150,b=1,T0=5,c=1,B=0.2))
```

[image]

If I set k manually (to e.g. 0, or 5) I get the function to run but with a poor fit, and a 'jump' at the value which I set k to.

[image]

Otherwise, if I include k as a parameter to be optimised within 'start', I get the error: *singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates*, which I understand is related to me choosing poor starting values?

Where am I going wrong, and how can I choose better starting values?

Comment: You can generate a grid or random set of k values and run nls with each value fixed.  The nls2 package can do that.

Comment: You really should try and fit a continuous function to this data ... That "jump" should not be possible with a good model.